# Horizontal align two react elements

Tags: css, reactjs

```
import React from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'
import { Dropdown, DropdownToggle, DropdownMenu, DropdownItem } from 'reactstrap';

class ResultsBar extends React.Component {
...
render() {
    return (
    <div>
    <h3>
        99 results
    </h3>
    <Dropdown isOpen={this.state.dropdownOpen} toggle={this.toggle}>
    <DropdownToggle caret>
      Dropdown
    </DropdownToggle>
    <DropdownMenu>
      {dropdown}
    </DropdownMenu>
    </Dropdown>
    <hr/>
    </div>
    );
    }
}
```

[image]

From the picture above, the component is not horizontally aligned

I want the react-strap dropdown element to float right of the  heading on the same line.

***EDIT 1:*** Using flex
`<div className={style.resultsBarDiv}>`

```
.results-bar-div {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
```

I'm trying to position h3 and dropdown at opposite ends of the window, `justify-content` isnt working

Comment: This has nothing to do with React. Just position 'em like any other elements – either set `display: inline-block` on `h3` and `Dropdown`, or use `display: flex` on the parent `div`, or use `float`, or …

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just use [flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/), set the container CSS to have `display: flex` this will put everything on the same line.

Look into using [styled components](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=styled%20components&rlz=1C1CHBF_en-GBGB784GB784&oq=styl&aqs=chrome.4.69i57j69i60l3j69i59l2.5839j0j4&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) when it comes to applying css to components in ReactJs in general.

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { render } from "react-dom";


import {
  Dropdown,
  DropdownToggle,
  DropdownMenu,
  DropdownItem
} from "reactstrap";


const divStyle = {
  display: 'flex',
  alignItems: 'center'
};

class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    dropdownOpen: true
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div style={divStyle}>
        <h3>99 results</h3>
        <Dropdown isOpen={this.state.dropdownOpen} toggle={this.toggle}>
          <DropdownToggle caret>
            Dropdown
    </DropdownToggle>
          <DropdownMenu>
          </DropdownMenu>
        </Dropdown>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I've changed that, now I'm trying to align the dropdown to the right of the  window. `display: flex; justify-content: space-between;` isnt working

Comment: By default, flex items are laid out in the source order. However, the order property controls the order in which they appear in the flex container. Look at flexbox guide, it shows you an example  of using `order: <some integer>`

Comment: ah ok thanks. `flex:1` and `justify-content: space-between` is what i wanted

Answer (score 1):

I'd apply styling with css.
You either directly style the dropdown, or give it a class via the className attribute.
Stlye it either with float, or display flex